# SED: How to comment and un-comment multiple lines in xml using sed

Tags: xml, shell, sed

my xml looks like this:

```
<map>
   <entry key="customerSaveRiskCodeProxy">  
     <ref bean="customerSaveRiskCodeProxy" />  
   </entry>  
   <entry key="checkRouteGenerationProxy">  
     <ref bean="checkRouteGenerationProxy" />  
   </entry>  
</map>
```

what is required is:

```
<map>
   <!--<entry key="customerSaveRiskCodeProxy">  
     <ref bean="customerSaveRiskCodeProxy" />  
   </entry>--> 
   <entry key="checkRouteGenerationProxy">  
     <ref bean="checkRouteGenerationProxy" />  
   </entry>  
</map>
```

i am able to comment and un-comment single line tags in xml using following command

`sed -i 's@<.*value="classpath:/quartz.properties".*@<!--<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/quartz.properties" />-->@g' task-Context.xml`

Comment: Regular expressions are not particularly suitable for manipulating nested formats. Is there a good reason why you are not using an XML parser for this, or generating the XML from a simpler format where it's easy to add or remove a block with a single regex?

Comment: @tripleee the objective is to automate the process of commenting and UN-commenting xml file as part of jenkins pipeline, i found sed is known way, how can i use xml parser as part of automation process